# Connection problem, BUS or Wire? - Altium Designer

Tags: altium, wire, error

I'm trying to make a panel with 1000 LEDs divided in two groups of 500 units and I want to put my schematic in A4 page. To do this I'm trying to use blocks, in this case 250 repeated blocks, separated in 2x125 blocks for each type of LED. But I have a problem with the connections. I already tried using wire, bus, bus+wire, but in all off tries I have problems when I compiled the project. Anyone can help me?

[image: TOP LEVEL and Error.]
[image: Inside of blocks.]

Regards,
Eduardo.

Comment: R U sure you have that repeat function right. it looks to me like it ought to be Repeat(Sheetname,Start,End) http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Multi-Channel+Design+Concepts

Comment: You're also mixing up bidirectional ports with unidirectional ports

Comment: Important question first: Do you have 1 connector for all LEDs or 125 individual connectors? If it's 1, you do not need all that wire/bus crazyness; If it's 125, place the connector into the subsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Your repeat definittion is wrong. Its repeat(scheetname, startindex, endindex) startindex can't be 0.

If you want to connect all LEDs to one connector you don't need all that repeat.
If you want many co nectors you need to move the connector to a sheet and repeet it. And dont name the net at the connector P1_Bus1 but P1_Bus.